# BackupSets.xml locked by SYSTEM

Tags: tfs

I have an installation of TFS 2018 which is split over an app and database server. Both servers run Windows Server 2016. Frequently I get an error that the scheduled backup has failed because BackupSets.xml is locked. 
Process Explorer shows that it is locked by SYSTEM. There is plenty of disk space on the backup disk (Currently 1.3TB and the full backup is 150GB).

The only way I have found to resolve this is to reboot both the app and database servers. This is not a viable long term solution to this.
Has anybody else encountered anything similar? Can you suggest a solution?

```
[23.03.2018 19:04:51] [Error]
Exception Message: The process cannot access the file 
'\\DatabaseServer\TFSBackups\BackupSets.xml' because it is being used by
another process. (type IOException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode,     
String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.BackupSets.Save(String folder)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.Jobs.DatabaseBackupJob.TakeTransactionalBackups (IVssRequestContext requestContext, BackupSettings settings, ITFLogger logger)    
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.Jobs.DatabaseBackupJob.RunBackupJob(IVssRequestContext requestContext, BackupJobType requestedJobType, String& resultMessage)

[23.03.2018 19:04:51] [Info] Backup Job Finished. Completed: Transactional.  Result = Failed
```

Comment: Did the issue only occurs  during the scheduled backup? What's the result if you manually do the back up, Did it works properly?

Comment: It also happens on a manual backup (i.e.: clicking on Take Full Backup Now). But it also isn't consistent. Sometimes I can replicate it with a manual backup, and sometimes not. Some scheduled backups after a reboot are completed, and then at some point it hits a wall. The longest uninterrupted period of successful backups has been several months. Then I will get a couple of months of non-stop failures.

Comment: Have you ruled out Antivirus software? It is a frequent cause of locked files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, suggest you to check the **Event View** on both server to see if there are more log info for troubleshooting. Also check the process especially for TFS related if some thing hangs on.

In this case you could try below solution:

1. Delete the `Backupsets.xml` file altogether
2. Reconfigured Backups using the wizard - Now that it didn't find the
   xml file at all it created a new one.
3. Ran a full backup - which should be successfully.

Double check if the scheduled backups will now also work from now on.

Comment: Unfortunately I could not delete Backupsets.xml as it was locked by the other process. I don't want to have to do this on a regular basis too, but would rather resolve the issue properly.
Restarting the servers helps, though I am not yet sure specifically which one had the file locked. I intent to test this the next time the issue occurs.

Comment: @DaveWhite Hi Dave, if this issue also occurs with a manual backup and you could not reproduce this issue **stably**. The issue may related to your server environment maybe hardware, network, firewall and so on. It maybe more complicated to narrow down the root cause. To delete the  Backupsets.xml, if it said locked. You should first disable scheduled backup in TFS Administrator Console first. If this works, then watch if you need a  regular basis. The Backupsets.xml may not generated properly before.

Comment: I'll monitor and see how everything goes. Thanks for your help, Patrick :-)